# Webhook tunnel not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webhooks, contentful

I've created a NextJS and Express app. There is some simple test routing like this:

```
const server = express();

server.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({ message: 'test' });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

When I visit `http://localhost:3000/api/test` in the browser or as a GET request in Postman, I successfully get the test message in a JSON object.

I've now setup a Webhook from the Contentful CMS. To test this locally, I'm using Ngrokthat routes to URL above. When I test the webhook, Ngrok accepts the request, but returns this error:

```
The connection to http://xxxxx.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:3000/api/test.

Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:3000/api/test and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp: lookup tcp/3000/api/test: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I've no idea what's going on here. My manual test proves the endpoint does work. Why would Ngrok not connect to it? As a secondary test I tried using Ultrahook instead of Ngrok but had the same problem.

EDIT:
The broad error from Ngrok is: `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: Are you calling `localhost` through the whole internet or is Ngrok running in your local network?

Comment: Ngrok doesn't care about client. If there is no client also, we can run ngrok.

Comment: make request to xxx.ngrok.com/api/test

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar When I make a local (browser/Postman) or webhook request to `xxx.ngrok.com/api/test` I get the above errors. However if I go directly to `http://localhost:3000/api/test` the endpoint works.

Comment: @Sv443 I believe the localhost is specific to my machine

Comment: which O.S you have?

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6)

Comment: Your node.js server is down. So, it didn't find when you hit that route. Check once again the server is up and running.

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar As I said, I tested the Node server endpoint in the browser and Postman. It is running and working fine. The issue seems to be with the tunnel.